# How do I split up an integer into groups of integers

Tags: ruby

This is my code. I'm trying to get a 2 dimensional array that each has five consecutive integers. This code doesn't work. So if the input is '1234567891' the output needs to be [[12345],[67891]]

```
def integer_groups(x)
    array = x.to_s.split('')
    new_array = []
    intervals = x / 5

    intervals.times { |n| new_array[n] << array.shift(5) }
    puts n
end
```

Comment: give one input data and output data also.. what is `x` and how should `n` look like ?

Comment: It doesn't run. Input data is any arbitrary integer that's a multiple of 5.

Comment: And what is the output to that?

Comment: still give the data and output you are expecting

Comment: If the input is 1234567891 then the output I would like is [[12345],[67891]]. My previous comment about the input needing to be a multiple of 5 makes no sense btw!

Comment: So you want an array of arrays of five-digit numbers?

Comment: If you realize that your description in the question does not make sense, then please edit it so that it makes sense.

Comment: ...and do that NOW, if you don't want more downvotes and/or have the question closed.  You mainly need what @Arup requested.

Comment: My apologies if you did the edit before I posted my comment. In any event, I believe that clarifies your question.

Answer (score 3):

Do as below :

```
1234567891.to_s.chars.each_slice(5).to_a
# => [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], ["6", "7", "8", "9", "1"]]
1234567891.to_s.chars.each_slice(5).map { |a| a.join.to_i }
# => [12345, 67891]
```

**update ( shortest and quickest)**

```
num  = 1234567891
num.to_s.scan(/\d{1,5}/).map { |n| [n.to_i] }
# => [[12345], [67891]]
```

- `scan(/\d{1,5}/)` - It will scan the digits from the string in a group of `5`. In case *string length is not divisible* by `5`, then it would also scan last chars as a group of length between `1 <= n < 5`. Here is `n` is the size of the string which `scan` is giving.

`/\d{1,5}/` can also be written as `/.{1,5}/`, as the source string contains only digits, no other kind of characters. `.` means any character except `\n`.

Comment: `chars`. You're missing an s :).

Comment: I feel there should be an easier way than scan, but you are probably correct. I would however change the regexp to `/.{1,5}/` in order to get the last chars if the string length is not evenly dividable by 5.